# How do I decrypt in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello fellow developers,

I have been stuck on this isssue for quite sometime now. All I want to do is somehow decrypt a column (ssn_or_ein) in my table (candidates) which was previously encrypted by the gem crypty_keeper.
https://github.com/jmazzi/crypt_keeper

What i have tried so far:
required the gem in Rails C and used the decrypt_table! against my Model

However, I am unable to catch the method

```
[pry(main)> Candidate.decrypt_table!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   Load (12.1ms)  SELECT  "candidates".* FROM "candidates" ORDER BY "candidates"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
   (4.8ms)  ROLLBACK
NameError: undefined local variable or method `crypt_keeper_fields' for #<Class:0x0000000007c5f038>
Did you mean?  crypt_keeper
```

Also tried putting the pre-existing code back in my Application

```
class Candidate < ApplicationRecord


   crypt_keeper :gateway_token, :ssn_or_ein, :e_in, encryptor: :active_support, key: ENV['ENCRYPTION_KEY'], salt: ENV['ENCRYPTION_SALT']
```

and I get an Active Support error

```
pry(main)> Candidate.decrypt_table!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   Load (609.8ms)  SELECT  "candidates".* FROM "candidates" ORDER BY "candidates"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
from /home/niketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.7@raisethemoney5.2.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
Caused by ArgumentError: invalid base64
```

This is the error i am getting.

Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: One idea which I had was to scale down to Rails 4 and try it, because on checking my GIt logs, I found out that the gem was removed post an update to Rails 5.2..but I don't want to jeopardize the project. Should I consider cloning it before doing the downgrade?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have rows in your table that are not encrypted and those cause the `Candidate.decrypt_table!` call to fail. Did you maybe remove the `crypt_keeper` line from the Candidate class and then add entries? If so you'll have to remove them or skip them...

Comment: Yes, the crpyt_keeper line didn't exist till a few months ago. And without it, there is no encryption and I am able to see all the values which were fed in for the last 2 months. That fetches me only 200 records, however the rest of the 2900 are encrypted because at that time, the crpyt_keeper was in usage, Thanks for reaching out sir

Comment: You'll have iterate over those 2900 rows and decrypt those fields. See here: https://github.com/jmazzi/crypt_keeper/blob/6994db6d7bba1c630e57fb16af4d676c3c2c4d79/lib/crypt_keeper/model.rb#L103

Comment: so, instead of doing Model.decrypt_table! , I  just ran each line under this method to do my decryption. I get the error for undifined method , against my table_name which is candidates